# Move whole document library in Workflow 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to move or copy and delete a whole `document library A` into another `document library B` in a 2010 workflow.

Is it possible to copy the whole library A or to copy another library inside A into B.

If it's not possible to copy the whole library is it possible to individually copy all the items in the document library?

Is it possible in workflow 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Copy List Item action** to copy the documents/list items from one library/list to another in SharePoint 2010 Designer, but SharePoint 2013 Designer; Copy List Item (SharePoint Designer 2013 supports only the document-copying action.) so its a yes, you can use SP 2013 Designer to copy items.

[What's changed in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/what-s-changed-in-sharepoint-designer#WhatsChangedSharePointDesigner2013_DiscontinuedFeatures)

please have a look at the below links too,

[Workflow: copy document from one library to another](https://cypher19.wordpress.com/workflow-copy-document-from-one-library-to-another/)

[SharePoint Designer workflow: Move a document from one library to another](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/sharepoint-designer-workflow-move-document-one-library-next.htm)

[Using workflow copy document from one library to another with metadata](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/66cf70de-7ff2-4c5a-9af7-a7cfaca78c54/using-workflow-copy-document-from-one-library-to-another-with-metadata?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Added to the above, SharePoint Designer Workflow is triggered based on 3 events and they are as below:

1. Manual (Manually running the workflow on item)
2. Item Created
3. Item Modified

Comment: I'm trying to move the whole library at once not just one item in it since the library is dynamic.

Comment: If it is single shot, then you can't do it using SP Designer workflow. Either you have to do it programmatically or PowerShell.